# C++ node.js module. cout not working?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon

Hi I am a noob in C++ trying to modify an existing native node module.

I am trying to add couts inside the module to print info I think is useful for me.

```
NAN_METHOD(Context2d::SetFillRule){
  Context2d *context = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Context2d>(info.This());
  cairo_t *ctx = context->context();
  String::Utf8Value str(info[0]);
  cout << "set method called";
  ...
}
```

The previous method is working but the cout is never shown.
Is it lost/shown during the node-gyp build? 
Have I done something wrong? is there a way to accomplish it?

Comment: How is the binary launched? Can we have some context? Are you sure to get through this particular method? Did you try to attach a debugger?

Comment: I configure and build it using the node-gyp as It is proposed. Yes the method is working for sure. The changes that should be made are done. The cout is the only thing I cant see. No I havent tested a debugger.

Comment: I guess the standard output is redirected to a log file. If you're under a *nix, you could `lsof pid` your process to find this log file.

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to learn N-API to make an addon for a nodejs project and just had the same issue. Adding `#include <iostream>` made `std::cout` available for use in my code. When I run my code by calling `node path_to_file.js` as I would for any nodejs project,  it successfully prints my data to the console. I know that you are using NAN and probably already overcame this issue a long time ago, but I felt it was important to give this answer since this showed up in my search results and there was not a good answer for beginners like me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing it to a log file instead (redirecting std::cout is a pain).

```
std::ofstream logFile("logfile.txt");
logFile << "set method called";
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout <<` in a Node.js C++ add-on is supposed to normally print to the console (the `stdout` of the `node` process).

If it doesn’t appear, it’s likely **segmentation faults** due to poor memory (instance lifespan) management. It kills the entire `node` process *silently*.

Answer (score -1):

The `cout << "some text"` will only works if you launch your binary straight from the command line.
I think it is not the case, as appears you are using it inside node.
So you should find some log output method from node libraries.

Answer (score -1):

If it is in windows you can try to make another console window.Then bind your contex to that window and redirect the print to there.

or write into a file.